# Getting "Element is not click-able" at point(345,802.5)

Tags: selenium, webdriver

The code is like below:

```
<div id="deposit-limit-187034" class="widget deposit-limit">
<div class="article deposit-limit-text">
<div class="hidden deposit-limit-edit" data-view-group="deposit-limit" data-view="deposit-limit-edit"   style="display: none;">
<div class="hidden deposit-limit-confirm" data-view-group="deposit-limit" data-view="deposit-limit-confirm"     style="display: none;">
<div class="hidden deposit-limit-set" data-view-group="deposit-limit" data-view="deposit-limit-set"     style="display: block;">
    <label>
<input type="radio" checked="checked" name="timelimit" value="0">
    <span class="custom-radio"></span>
            24 timer
    </label>
    </div>
    <div class="group-field">
    <label>
    <input type="radio" name="timelimit" value="1">
    <span class="custom-radio"></span>
            7 dage
    </label>
    </div>
    <div class="group-field">
    <label>
    <input type="radio" name="timelimit" value="2">
    <span class="custom-radio"></span>
            30 dage
    </label>
    </div>
<p> </p>
<fieldset class="amount-field-container">
<p></p>
<p class="deposit-error deposit-limit-set-error hidden"> Vælg venligst en tidsramme og indtast et gyldigt beløb     </p>
<button class="btn has-icon-suffix deposit-set">
</form>
</div>
<div class="hidden deposit-limit-active" data-view-group="deposit-limit" data-view="deposit-limit-active"   style="display: none; opacity: 0;">
```

The X path is as follows:

//*[(@data-view='deposit-limit-set') and (@style='display: block;')]//*[(@class='field-group field-row radio-container')]//div//label/input[contains(@name,'timelimit') and contains(@value, '2')]

Sometimes it clicks the radio button and sometimes I get "Element is not click-able" at point(345,802.5).

Please help

Comment: If you run the test and watch Selenium click through, are there any elements that overlap with this element/become in front of it?

Comment: Yes, its clicking through when i see the screen. But sometimes it fails and sometimes i get "Element is not click-able" at point(345,802.5).